# Wordpress site migration from Localhost to new host no CSS/JS

Tags: database, wordpress, migration, hosting, local

I have a Wordpress site that I developed with Local and has localhost url. I got a new hosting plan and domain name and I successfully pointed the domain to the new hosting.

I tried to do the migration and I used the Wordpress plugin "WP Migrate" and I performed the find and replace using the new domain url.

I forgot to do a backup of the database before doing the find and replace and now my site doesn't show any photos, styling and JS.

Is there any way I can restore the previous localhost url and do the process again?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check the wp_options table, if URL is properly replaced.
2. Or, you can backup DB and again replace new URL to localhost URL to get back the DB to previous state.
3. The URL replace will affect only serialised array strings only.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please save parmalink on live site.

Then check your option table site url and home url

Try find replace old url